# How to create NFT in Statemint?

Tags: statemint, uniques

How to create nft in statemint in javascript.and how to set the nft images. can any one provide the example. my test code go wrong.

```
 const wsProvider = new polkadot.WsProvider("wss://westmint-rpc.polkadot.io");
 const api = await polkadot.ApiPromise.create({provider:wsProvider});

let tx = api.tx.utility.batchAll([
  api.tx.uniques.create(classId, ADDR_1);
  api.tx.uniques.setAttribute(classId, null,"Link","https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmRdpVRCLxN51vNnYCRr2is1w6UVpT3mR8YDov9ktPmKub"), // this tx will crash
    ]);
tx.signAndSend(pair);
```

Comment: It is crashing because you are hitting the [`ValueLimit`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/polkadot-parachains/westmint/src/lib.rs#L498).

Comment: Next time please provide the associated error message. Thanks!

Comment: well. ````api.tx.uniques.setAttribute(classId, null,"Link","https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmRdpVRCLxN51vNnYCRr2is1w6UVpT3mR8YDov9ktPmKub"), // this tx will crash
```` this line will crash in rust

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using the [`uniques`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/pallet_uniques/pallet/index.html) pallet to create non-fungible assets:

```rust
export const createNonFungibleAssets = async () => {
    let tx = api.tx.utility.batchAll([
        api.tx.uniques.create(classId, admin),
        api.tx.uniques.setAttribute(classId, 1, "cid", "FgsChd2hVdrJ6bfo3WBcTW4iZnpHm8TEzWkLHmLpXhF68k"),
        api.tx.uniques.setAttribute(classId, 2, "cid", "JrqChd2hKbrJ6bfo3WBcTW4iZnpHm8TEzWkLHmLpXhF68d"),
        api.tx.uniques.setAttribute(classId, 3, "cid", "LxmChd2hSsrJ6bfo3WBcTW4iZnpHm8TEzWkLHmLpXhF68a"),
        api.tx.uniques.mint(classId, 1, owner),
        api.tx.uniques.mint(classId, 2, owner),
        api.tx.uniques.mint(classId, 3, owner)
    ])
    tx.signAndSend(pair, ({ status }) => {
        if (status.isInBlock) {
          console.log(`included in ${status.asInBlock}`);
        }
      });
}
```

Typically you will not store the image on-chain. You would use a third-party service to store the images and store the hash on-chain.

Comment: !!the answer you give is so bad